# Pagination help command Discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How do I use pagination with this code?
I dont have any idea how to do it.

```
const {MessageEmbed} = require("discord.js")
module.exports = {
    name: "help",
    description: "Pokazuje wszystkie komendy",
    usage: "[Command name]",
    cooldown: 5,
  
     run(msg, args) {
        const arg = args[0]
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        
      const { commands } = msg.client
      const data = []
      
        
      if (!args.length) {
          
          data.push(embed.setTitle("**Komendy:**"))
          data.push(embed.setDescription(commands.map((command) => command.name).join(`\n`)), true)
          data.push(embed.setFooter(
              `\nZastosowanie\`${PREFIX}help [command name]\` aby dostać info o komendzie!`))

          return msg.channel.send(data, {split: true})
          
        }

        //podane argumenty
        const name = args[0].toLowerCase()  
        const command = 
        commands.get(name) ||
        commands.find((c) => c.aliases && c.aliases.includes(name))
        if (!command) {
            return msg.reply("Zła komenda!")
        }
        data.push(embed.setDescription(`**Nazwa:** ${command.name} \n **Użycie:** ${PREFIX}${command.name} ${command.usage} \n **Cooldown:** ${command.cooldown || 3} second(s)`))



        msg.channel.send(data, { split:true })
    },
  }
```

Without pagination, it looks silly.
The commands are below each other and it doesn't look very nice.
Alternatively, the commands can be next to each other.
For example, on the left moderation and commands below, and on the right 4fun and also commands

Answer (score 0):

You can create this yourself however, it would easier to use a module like [discord.js-pagination](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js-pagination)

To use their example:

```js
const paginationEmbed = require('discord.js-pagination');
 
// Footers arent needed, this is added by the module
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const embed1 = new MessageEmbed();
const embed2 = new MessageEmbed();

// Create an array of embeds
pages = [
    embed1,
    embed2,
];

// first 2 args are required
paginationEmbed(msg, pages, emojiList, timeout);
```